# The difference between 添削 and 訂正

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I used to always use `訂正{ていせい}` rather than `添削{てんさく}` to mean "correction", but recently I haven't really seen `訂正` being used. When used in the context of correcting English translations etc, it seems to me `添削` is used almost exclusively.

What is the difference in nuance between these two words?

Comment: i see 修正 on lang8 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"訂正" seems to mean to correct an error. And "添削" is to check whether an article or answer is correct or appropriately written, and if not, correct accordingly.

So we can say "誤りを訂正する" or "文章を添削する".

When used with translation, usually a whole translation is to corrected, not a single mistake, so "添削" is used.

btw: In English test in Japan, there seems to be a kind of problem called "間違い訂正".

Comment: As an additional comment, 添削 is usually done for educational purpose.